# How do I load an image on a custom object which inherits the picturebox?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, picturebox

I'm trying to write a program which has an expandable image feed that keeps adding pictures as I go.  Before I bite off that chunk I'm just trying to get test going with a custom image class which will hold a little bit of extra info on top of the `picturebox` object.  The issue I'm having is that my object (`oSlideItem` as `clsSlideItem`) which inherits the `picturebox` doesn't seem to load a picture at run time.  I've tried two different methods which are mentioned in help and on this forum and I can't seem to get a picture at run time.  I haven't found anything that mentions my specific situation which is inheriting the `picturebox`.

I tried setting the image location and size properties before loading the picture, didn't change anything.

Are there some extra steps I need to do in order to initiate the picturebox image since I am using the functionality in an inherited state instead of a native picturebox object ?

I am also putting these image holding objects into a collection as you can see.  I tested loading a picture without putting it into a collection and nothing changed so I don't think that is the issue.  I am Assuming that once I add an object to a collection that the object inside the collection and the object outside the collection are decoupled.  I didn't do a good test for that yet.

```
Public Class clsSliders
Private clFeedItems As New Collection 'collection of all feed items
Private oFeed As New clsFeed 'feed organizer layer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'build Feed
    Dim oSlideItem As clsSlideItem 'feed item layer

    'make collection of slider objects
    oSlideItem = New clsSlideItem
    oSlideItem.setRank(1, oFeed)
    oSlideItem.ImageLocation = "C:\Users\nathan\Pictures\Chicago_River_from_Lake_Street_bridge.jpg"
    oSlideItem.Load()

    clFeedItems.Add(oSlideItem, 1)

    oSlideItem = New clsSlideItem
    oSlideItem.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\nathan\Pictures\ReindeerPowerLines.png")
    oSlideItem.setRank(2, oFeed)

    'add to collection
    clFeedItems.Add(oSlideItem, 2)

    oSlideItem = New clsSlideItem
    oSlideItem.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\nathan\Pictures\TianmenMountain.jpg")
    oSlideItem.setRank(3, oFeed)

    'add to collection
    clFeedItems.Add(oSlideItem, 3)

End Sub

'other subs and properties
End Class
```

and my second class:

```
Public Class clsSlideItem
Inherits PictureBox

Private iFeedRank As Integer 'current rank position

Public Sub setRank(rank As Integer, oFeed As clsFeed)
    If Not IsNothing(oFeed) Then
        Me.Left = oFeed.Left(rank)
        Me.Top = oFeed.Top(rank)
        Me.Width = oFeed.Width(rank)
        Me.Height = oFeed.Height(rank)
        iFeedRank = rank
    End If
End Sub

'other subs and properties
End Class
```

`oFeed` as `clsFeed` is basically a structure which I wrote as a class so that I can have extra functionality.  It's not really in the scope of this issue since that part of the code is working. I didn't include it because I didn't want to clutter up this post.

Comment: MS Visual Studio 2012, Win7 32x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the pictureboxes are never being added to the form controls collection. Add this

```
Me.Controls.Add(oSlideItem)
```

after

```
oSlideItem = New clsSlideItem
```

A control won't be visible on (or contained by) the form until it is added to the Controls collection. I think the images are being read just fine, only they're not displayed on the form. You can see by setting a breakpoint after the load and looking at the properties of oSlideItem (Shift-F9).

Comment: Well by golly it worked @xpda!  Thank you very much for your quick answer!